# javascript/angular: add 'line break' via string

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this method in my .ts file that creates a string out of obj.date and obj.status.
Now I'm using multiple(eight, to be exact) \xa0 (a hex encoded nbsp) to make some space between the date and the status.
The resulting string: **17/11/2020       done**
 is then bound in the template.


I would rather use a line break instead so that it would look like so:
**17/11/2020

done**

```
dateWithStatus(obj) {
  return
    moment.utc(object.date).format(DATE_FORMAT)
    + Array(8).fill('\xa0').join('')
    + object.status;
}
```

My question is - what hex code should I use instead of **\xa0** to force the line break?
Neither **\n**, nor **\r\n** seem to work.

PS: Yes, I did search the stackoverflow (among other sites) for the answer, to no avail.


**=== update ===**
I tested the string literal thingy in the (Angular) template file.

component.ts

```
testString = `abcd
efgh
ijkl`;
```

component.html

```
<span>{{testString}}</span>
```

**RESULT** : all the letters are in one line
abcd efgh ijkl

Comment: Can't you use template literals (back ticks)?

Comment: I did try the back ticks, but the result was the same. All it yielded was one space.

Comment: All of the answers deal with the <h2> tag that I've chosen only for testing purposes. The tag containing the text in the app is actually <span>, so I changed it in the test example too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the ways could be adding a class to your element, say, `testString`, like so:-

```
.testString{
white-space:pre
}
```

`white-space:pre` should allow breaking at `\n` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line break in your string and then bind the innerText property of the element:

```
<h2 [innerText]="testString"></h2>

testString = 'first line' + ' \n ' + ' second line';
```

Comment: @PaxForce sorry you are right with innerText you need to use \n to have the new line. It is usefull when displaying text captured via a textarea input and preservers the new line and white spaces

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `safeHtml` pipe.

```js
// component.ts
...
testString = 'Hello<br>world!';
...

// component.html
<h2 [innerHtml]="testString | safeHtml"></h2>
```